# How to get current URL in NET Core 2.0

Tags: url, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

How to get current URL?
I try that:

*Program.cs*

```
var location = new Uri($"{Request.Scheme}://{Request.Host}{Request.Path}{Request.QueryString}");
```

or

```
public string BuildAbsolute(PathString path, QueryString query = default(QueryString), FragmentString fragment = default(FragmentString))
    {
        var rq = HttpContent.Request;
        return Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions.UriHelper.BuildAbsolute(rq.Scheme, rq.Host, rq.PathBase, path, query, fragment);
    }
```

Visual Studio does not find "Request"

The only thing I need is to take the current URL and Host / Path

Comment: Program.cs runs in order to start the kestrel web server, only after kestrel launches does it begin listen for web requests so there is no web request at the time when Program.cs main is executed.

Comment: for what you need the url? when you need the url most likey you won't need it in program.cs there you can just set it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run your functions inside Startup.cs inside Configure using middleware. You can do

```
app.Use(async (context,next)=>{
     //Do what you want with context,which is HttpContext
     await next.Invoke();
});
```

Comment: This is useful to make basic context information like current URL available inside whole app without bloating it with HttpContextAccessor.

Comment: How do you pass down context properties to your controller from the middle ware?